# Issue with comparing character values inside of a string in C for CS50 subsitution problem

Tags: arrays, c, comparison, cs50

The program specifications are

Design and implement a program, substitution, that encrypts messages using a substitution cipher.

Implement your program in a file called substitution.c in a directory called substitution.

Your program must accept a single command-line argument, the key to use for the substitution. The key itself should be case-insensitive, so whether any character in the key is uppercase or lowercase should not affect the behavior of your program.

If your program is executed without any command-line arguments or with more than one command-line argument, your program should print an error message of your choice (with printf) and return from main a value of 1 (which tends to signify an error) immediately.

If the key is invalid (as by not containing 26 characters, containing any character that is not an alphabetic character, or not containing each letter exactly once), your program should print an error message of your choice (with printf) and return from main a value of 1 immediately.

Your program must output plaintext: (without a newline) and then prompt the user for a string of plaintext (using get_string).

Your program must output ciphertext: (without a newline) followed by the plaintext’s corresponding ciphertext, with each alphabetical character in the plaintext substituted for the corresponding character in the ciphertext; non-alphabetical characters should be outputted unchanged.

Your program must preserve case: capitalized letters must remain capitalized letters; lowercase letters must remain lowercase letters.

After outputting ciphertext, you should print a newline. Your program should then exit by returning 0 from main.

I am able to accomplish all of them except for making the duplicate inputs

I suppose this part of the code has the issue, but I do not understand exactly why.

I keep getting a duplicate value which is != when I input into the terminal
./substitution YTNSHKVEFXRBAUQZCLWDMIPGJO

I don't understand why exactly, because the code itself seems alright. It checks inside the array if the value is a duplicate, and then increases the value counter, but it won't work.

When I did a test run in vscode debugging, I got at the end value of duplicate for this equal to 25, which is beyond my understanding how.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a11Qa.png)

My code below is

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    //Check is to keep track if it fulfills all requirements
    int check = 0;

    // Check if the agrc values are equal to 2 or not, if not have to ask for it again
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("./substitution key\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        check++;
    }

    // Get the length of the string
    int n = strlen(argv[1]);
    // Check if the length of inputted characters is 26 or not
    if (n != 26)
    {
        printf("Key must contain 26 characters\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        check++;
    }

    // Check if there are 26 letters
    int letterCheck = 0;
    // To get number of digits
    // Loop through out the second input through terminal to see if the values are correct
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(argv[1][i]))
        {
            letterCheck++;
        }
    }
    if (letterCheck != 26)
    {
        printf("Key must contain 26 letters\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        check++;
    }

    // Check for duplicates
    int duplicate = 0;
    for (int a = 0; a < n; a++)
    {
        for (int b = 1; b < n; b++)
        {
            if (toupper(argv[1][a]) == toupper(argv[1][b]))
            {
                duplicate++;
            }
        }
    }
    if (duplicate != 0)
    {
        printf("Key must not contain repeated characters\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        check++;
    }
    if (check == 4)
    {
        string plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");
        // Get the length of the string
        int length = strlen(plaintext);

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            if (isupper(plaintext[i]))
            {
                plaintext[i] = plaintext[i] - 65;
                plaintext[i] = argv[1][(int)plaintext[i]];
                plaintext[i] = toupper(plaintext[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                plaintext[i] = plaintext[i] - 97;
                plaintext[i] = argv[1][(int)plaintext[i]];
                plaintext[i] = tolower(plaintext[i]);
            }
        }
        printf("ciphdertext: %s\n", plaintext);
        return 0;
    }
}```

'''
    int duplicate = 0;
    for (int a = 0; a < n; a++)
    {
        for (int b = 1; b < n; b++)
        {
            if (toupper(argv[1][a]) == toupper(argv[1][b]))
            {
                duplicate++;
            }
        }
    }
    if (duplicate != 0)
    {
        printf("Key must not contain repeated characters\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        check++;
    }
'''
````

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of the problem. There is something wrong with your posted code. After the function `main`, you seem to have some additional code which causes compiler errors.

Comment: Your inner loop should be from `a+ 1` rather than `1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set your 'b' value to '1' so every-time it loops it begins from one. So when your outer loop is 1 your inner loop will be also start from one and your duplicate flag will increment. Your loop should be like the one below

```
 for (int a = 0; a < n; a++)
    {
        for (int b = a + 1; b < n; b++)
        {
            if (toupper(argv[1][a]) == toupper(argv[1][b]))
            {
                duplicate++;
            }
        }
    }
```